# What ram to buy without upgrading the motherboard

Tags: memory, motherboard

[System info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4OXD.png) Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 processor and 
ECG3510M motherboard.

I heard that DDR3 isn't compatible with my motherboard so i would like to know what ram to buy or is upgrading the motherboard any cheaper/efficient.

Comment: Intel ECG3510M only supports DDR2 RAM. Going for an upgrade I suggest going for what is compatible for your Intel Core 2 Duo E7200 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Searching Intel's site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18005/BIOS-Update-ECG3510M-86A-?product=34689), the model of your board is DG35EC, not ECG3510M.  ECG3510M is the BIOS update version. [Intel specs for the board](http://ark.intel.com/products/34689) show it supports non-ECC DDR2 667/800 with a max of 8 GB. So, you are correct DDR3 would not be compatible with this board. The physical pins would not even line up. See the comparison graphic on the [DDR2 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM)

I would recommend you try to buy RAM that is listed on [Intel's tested memory list for the board](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards/000006758.html).

It's difficult to answer your question of whether just upgrading the RAM is cheaper/more-efficient because you did not tell us how much RAM is currently in it, or what you generally do with the PC. If for example, all you do is email and web-browsing, then yes, upgrading RAM would probably be the way to go. But if you're playing video games or doing any intense processing (converting videos), you might consider upgrading the board, processor, and RAM (or even just buying a new PC).